# Can you access firestore client-side without firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a counter in my react front-end that I want to ***display a document value from my firestore database***. However, I can't seem to access the firestore data, the code below results in the following error:

### Navbar.js (client-side code)

```
import { db, app, functions } from "./firebase";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  doc,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  getDocFromCache,
} from "firebase/firestore";


async function checker() {
  const querySnap = await getDocs(collection(db, "Count")); //Count is collections name
  querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
}
```

### Error Message

> Navbar.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I haven't implemented any firebase auth (although feels like I will need to implement before deploying), and I have tried adjusting my firestore rules (shown below, although I know they are too vulnerable).

### firestore.rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

### My goals are:

1. Make a successful read of firestore data
2. Adust security rules to be more secure
3. Figure out if auth is necessary to add based on my needs here

Would appreciate any and all advice, I am still new to firebase.

Here is my config file if that is helpful?

### firebase.js (in same directory as Navbar.js)

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from 'firebase/functions';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: //Hiding my data for this post
  authDomain: 
  projectId: 
  storageBucket: 
  messagingSenderId: 
  appId: 
  measurementId: 
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);


export default {app, db, analytics, functions};
```

Comment: If you haven't implemented Firebase Authentication, then this rules will always reject access: `if request.auth != null`. This is all quite well documented though, so I recommend reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started (and watch the video in there too), https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules, and some of the previous questions about the same error message: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+FirebaseError%3A+Missing+or+insufficient+permissions.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I want my front-end to be able to read a firestore document, but I don't plan to have a "sign-in" authentication feature on my app to deal with users, is there a way to still give it permission to read the value? Or in that case, is it best to call a cloud function get method that will retrieve the data and pass it to the front-end? I will need to change my firestore rules, just not sure beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your preferred requirements, I would suggest using [custom security rules(data validation)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) if you want to use specific rules in accessing a specific document/collection.

You can check the sample Firestore rules below wherein it does not require authentication as long as the collection matches the value of the field.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to read data if the document has the 'visibility'
    // field set to 'public'
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read: if resource.data.visibility == 'public';
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.

Comment: I have tried to leave one specific document open to public reading but Firebase still gives me a warning that it is vulnerable to an attack that drives up read prices. Is there a way to securely make a read from the front-end or do I need to make a cloud function to retrieve this data securely from the backed with admin SKD?